# Resolve FileIO does not exist in nameespace Microsoft.VisualBasic in .NET Core console app

Tags: c#, .net-core

In Visual Studio 2015 (.NET 4.5.2) I am able to use the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace (used for text parsing) by simply right clicking reference and ticking the `MicrosoftVisualBasic` checkbox.

[image: Screen Shot of successfully adding reference]

With .NET Core Console App I have no such option so I get an error

> The type or namespace 'FileIO' does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.VisualBasic.

I installed the NuGet package `Microsoft.VisualBasic` however this has not helped.

[image: Issues with .NetCOre console application]

Comment: I read recently that the .NET Core team has not fully implemented the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` library yet.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is no way to use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` on .Net Core currently.

You might want to weigh in with your use case on [the *Microsoft.VisualBasic functions port* issue on the corefx repo](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14300) (so that MS knows this is a namespace that some people want ported to .Net Core). Another issue that might be of interest is [the request to make `Microsoft.VisualBasic` open source as part of Reference Source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8808) (which would likely allow you to copy&paste the code into your solution).